# Show custom error message when debug_mode = 0

Tags: cakephp-2.4

I am a newbie in CakePHP and I can not deal with one thing. If I enter to the URL controller, that does not exist, I get an error message **Missing Controller** with notice: 
If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp

This is OK, I did it and now it is ok-> i get text from view missing_controller.ctp. But this works only, when debug_mode = 2.

On production, when I set debug_mode to 0, I get only error - **Error: The requested address '/xx' was not found on this server.** View missing_controller.ctp is not shown

I found a few solutions, but nothing helped me so far.

Can you please advise how can I see missing_controller.ctp if controller, that does not exist when  debug_mode is set to 0?

I am using CakePHP 2.4.6. 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this file:

```
app/View/Errors/error400.ctp
```

This is shown when debug is 0.